# how to use jQuery click function with javascript OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, onclick

I want to use :

> $("...").animate()

with loading an `onClick` JavaScript Ajax . But there are some issues with that:

I try using jQuery like this :

```
function Ajaxrequest(){
var xmlHttp;try{xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();return xmlHttp;}
    catch (e){
        try{xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        return xmlHttp;
    }
    catch (e){
        try{xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        return xmlHttp;}
    catch (e){
        alert("Browser Not support Ajax");
        return false;}
    }
}

function showtopic(str) {
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(document).height()
    }, 2000);
    var xmlHttp = Ajaxrequest();
    var issolve = "<a href=\'#topic\' title=\'دادن امتیاز\' class=\"fade\" id=\'solved\' onclick=\"showbest('faq.php?like=2lkha96slh','solved' , 'notsolved')\">+1 مشکلم حل شد</a><a href=\"http://my-bb.ir\" id=\"notsolved\" class=\"fade\" title=\"پرسیدن سوال\" target=\"_blank\" >نبابا حل نشد ! میخوام سوال بپرسم</a></li><br/><br/>";
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("showtopic").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState > 0 && xmlHttp.readyState < 4) {
            document.getElementById("tftopic").innerHTML = loadingmessage;
        }
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("showtopic").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("issolved").innerHTML = issolve;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", str, true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

but it didn't work!

Then I made a jQuery inline code like this :

```
jQuery('.go-bott').click(function () {
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: (jQuery(document).height() * 0.9)
      }, 2000);
      return false;
  });
```

and use that beside JavaScript `onClick`, but Ajax doesn't let jQuery run (this code will run on a simple class).

How I can have a `onClick` JavaScript Ajax with a jQuery scroll ***or*** Can I use JavaScript to scroll page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do realize jQuery is javascript?

Comment: please fix your formatting, very difficult to understand the code in its current format

Comment: Where do you call showtopic(..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Some Things

You should do following things just to be extra safe:

- In your callback function:

  ```
  if (xmlHttp.readyState > 0 && xmlHttp.readyState < 4) {
      document.getElementById("tftopic").innerHTML = loadingmessage;
  } else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("showtopic").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("issolved").innerHTML = issolve;
  } else {
      // do your error handling here
  }
  ```

---

And you could optimize some code to use more jQuery:

- You can set the innerHTML of an element instead of using document.getElementById("element-name").innerHTML = 'string' by using jQuery:

  ```
  $('#element-name').html('string'); // or jQuery(...).html(...)
  ```
- You could write $(...) instead of jQuery(...), saves you some typing :) (don't use when using jQuery.noConflict())

---

### 2. onclick

```html
<div id="some-element" onclick="showtopic('your-attribute')"></div>
```

---

### 3. scrollTop

Use 'px' when animating scrollTop to a number greater than zero.

```
scrollTop: (jQuery(document).height() * 0.9) + 'px'
```

---

### 4. Let me get something straight

It seems you don't quite know what jQuery is in relation to JavaScript. JavaScript is a **programming language**. jQuery is a **library or plugin**, written in JavaScript. So, jQuery inline code = JavaScript inline code.

Comment: I edit my post , actully i have a Ajaxrequest() function to your first point .thnx alot let me try dear stefan

Comment: I understand your tips stefan but my code still not scrolling !××!  I put them here http://demo.mellat-design.ir/demo.js

Comment: @mehdi Even scrolling with your function seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/chfdmthj/1/

Comment: !!! Then I think it is because if ajax my codes aren't working ! 
Your codes don't have ajax , and just load scrolling with function ... 
http://demo.mellat-design.ir/faq.php
 this is the page.

Comment: @mehdi Sorry, I can't find the element that calls showtopic on the page, I can only find showbest and showlevel. Where's it?

Comment: its in a php file and will be displayed after click on one of .top right colorfull elements, and then a menu will display in left of that , then after clicking on one of them it load data from Database and show list
then with clicking a <li> showtopic display topic on bottom of page .

Comment: for Ex :  click on (تازه وارد و مبتدی) then on (دامنه و هاست);

Comment: @mehdi Ah I see, developer console tells me that $ is not a function, use jQuery('html,body').animate(...) instead of $('html,body').animate(...); that's because you free $ to other libraries using jQuery.noConflict() before

Comment: Wow ! Thanx man , Perfect help , You are a big man . Can be in touch? do u have skype or ...

Comment: @mehdi Sure, just email me your skype name to hello @ wimeme.ch

Comment: @thnx again , i send you an email